# How to process HTML form that has dynamic elements?

Tags: php, jquery, html, webforms

Apologies if this is somewhat of a duplicate question, I did see others but I didn't quite find what I was looking for.

You can see my code in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnWMq/

As you can see, I have named my drop-downs `tags[]`, `values[]` and `operands[]` - i.e. as arrays so that whatever PHP page we set as the action of the form will be able to process the dynamically added drop-downs.

I'm just a bit confused on how to split out the values once they are sent to the page dealing with the form submission so if anyone can shed some light I would be very grateful.

Regards,

Martin

**UPDATE**

Hi, thanks for your replies.

so far I have changed the action of the form to `advancedsearch.php` using the `POST` method and here is the code:

```
<?php
    $tags = $_POST['tags'];
    $operands = $_POST['operands'];
    $values = $_POST['values'];

   foreach ($tags as $t)
   {
       echo "$t<br />";
   }

   foreach ($operands as $o) 
   {
       echo "$o<br />";
   }

  foreach ($values as $v) 
  {
      echo "$v<br />";
  }

 ?>
```

This gets the values ok but it just needs tweaked so I can get it into a format for querying a MySQL database, so something like `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tag1 operand1 value1 radio_button_value(AND or OR) tag2 operand2 value2 radio_button_value` etc

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So when you click 'Advanced Search' you want to get the values of the <select>s ?

Comment: Yes, to get all the values and get it into a format in order to query a MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed it by doing the following:

```
<?php

$tags = $_POST['tags'];
$operands = $_POST['operands'];
$values = $_POST['values'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];

print "<pre>";
print_r ($_POST);

$query .="WHERE ";

for ($counter=0 ; $counter < count($tags) ; $counter++)
{

    if ($counter>0)
    {
        $query .= "$cat ";
    }

    $query .= sprintf("%s %s '%s' ", $tags[$counter] , $operands[$counter] ,   
    $values[$counter]) ;
}

echo "$query";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> So when you click 'Advanced Search'
>   you want to get the values of the
>   s ? – Alex Thomas 6 mins ago

If this is the case, then this should help: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnWMq/1/

I've done the code to work on the clicking of a span as i didn't want to disrupt your code. Heres my code:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    tags = $("select[name='tags[]'] option:selected").val();
    operands = $("select[name='operands[]'] option:selected").val();
    values = $("select[name='values[]'] option:selected").val();
    output = tags+" "+operands+" "+values;
    alert(output);
});
```

If this is not what you're after, i'll try again :)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply, I've made an update to my question. Just realised I haven't supplied the radio button value to the php page just incase you get confused!

I've got it submitting to a separate PHP page but would be nice to do it using AJAX instead once we have ironed out how to get it into a query.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you will receive 3 post variables as arrays and they should have equal length (in term of count). You will need code like that:

```
$filterCount = count($_POST['tags']);
$filters = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $filterCount; $i++) {
    $filters[] = array('tag' => $_POST['tags'][$i], 'operand' => $_POST['operands'][$i], 'value' => $_POST['values'][$i]);
}
```

Also you can try different approach. For example you can use different name for each filter like that:

```
<select name="filter1[tag]" class="tags">
<option>tags</option>
</select>

<select name="filter1[operand]" class="operands">
<option>operands</option>
</select>

<select name="filter1[value]" class="values">
<option>values</option>
</select>
```

When you clone the filter you have to change the name to filterN.